# $location.hash() breaking my function

Tags: angularjs, autoscroll

I'm very close to finishing up my page, and I ran into this odd bug.

When I use ng-include, the pages load fine, but they resume scrolling from the previous position, so they don't start at the top with every click.

I resorted to using anchor scroll, but it doesn't work properly. I have to click the link again, for it to load the contents, and if I click the same link again, it offsets the page to some weird position.

This is my code in the controller:

```
    $scope.toPage = function (index, id) {
    $scope.missiveIndex = index;
    $scope.contentsDown();
    $location.hash(id);
};
```

and this is the HTML part:

```
<article id="{{articles.ids}}" class="stories-anim" ng-repeat="articles in stories" ng-hide="!isMissiveSlideIndex($index)" ng-include="articles.content" [autoscroll]>
</article>
```

the id is passed in via `ng-click="ng-click="toPage($index, button.ids);"`

is there a way to put the location.hash in the [onload] expression and autoscroll that way?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably the anchor scroll didn't work because the content of the page was not fully loaded when it was called.

You can solve that by using a timeout.

```
$timeout(function() {
  $anchorScroll();
},500);
```

Comment: thank you. i managed to hack it by actually using a 0sec timeout, for the first loads. if you go back to the previous article, it retains the scroll position